# How to communicate effectively between Angular directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have come across redundant logic needed for my application that I would like to get into a directive form where I am not convoluting the controller scopes with view properties.  The idea is simple. I want 2 directives (a parent and a child) with a 1 to many relationship (1 parent element has X number of child elements).

The directive is simply a list where the user can click on an element (child directive) and have the element add a `active` class while all OTHER siblings have the `active` class removed.

The control is basically a radio button (same functionality), I just wanted to make it generic for any type of element.  This is what I have so far:

```
app.directive('skSelect', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        controller: function($scope){
            this.reset = function(){
               //HERE I WANT TO SET ALL CHILDREN sk-select-item DIRECTIVES TO isSelected = false SOMEHOW
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

        }
    }
});

app.directive('skSelectItem', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        require:'^skSelect',
        replace:false,
        template:'<div ng-class="{active: isSelected}" ng-click="select()"></div>',
        link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

            scope.isSelected = false;


            //scope.$watch('isSelected', function(isSelected){
            //    if(isSelected){
            //        element.addClass('active');
            //    }else{
            //        element.removeClass('active');
            //    }
            //});

            scope.select = function(){
                ctrl.reset();
                scope.isSelected = true;
            }




        }
    }
});
```

So my problem lies with trying to have a `reset()` function where the parent needs to communicate to the children to set their isSelected property to `false`. I am also not sure whether I should use a `template` in the `skSelectItem` directive in order to add/remove the `active` class and to bind the click event OR if I should just use `element.on('click')` and `scope.$watch('isSelected', ...)` in order to accomplish this?

Comment: you should try to use scope.$emit and subscribe the child directives to a event that s throw on the parent. I will post an answer on a minute.

Comment: ok so just have the parent $emit an event and have the children listen to the event and set `isSelected = false` when the event occurs? That sounds pretty solid to me. How about use the template? I want to be able to use this on any type of element

Comment: I am writing, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to handle the comunication betwen directives.Here are two good examples of how you can do it.

### General Concerns

On the directive definition if you are using a template like `<div ng-class="{active: isSelected}" ng-click="select()"></div>` you must specify the scope property to true, to make a child scope for the [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). otherwise you will share the variable on the parent scope.

### Using $broadcast, $on

in this case the parent directive could send an event to notify the child directives that something change.

in your code:

```
// on the parent directive.
this.reset = function() {                                    
     $scope.$broadcast('skSelect::reset');
}

//on the child directive. remember to set the scope to true.

link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

                    scope.$on('skSelect::reset', function (event) {
                        scope.isSelected = false;
                    });
```

This is the standart solution ,but it has some problems when you are using nested directives of the same types. Because the emit event could't be stoped, the am event throw on the parent is listen by all the child directives.

to solve this you should generate a random key to use on the name of the event.

```
        function buildEventName (key) {
          return 'skSelect::reset' + key;
        }

// parent controller 

controller: function($scope){

                    this.eventKey = Math.random() * 999999; // random key here.

                    this.reset = function() {
                        $scope.$emit(buildEventName(this.eventKey));
                    }
                },
```

// child link function

```
link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

                        scope.$on(buildEventName(ctrl.eventKey), function (event) {
                            scope.isSelected = false;
                        });
```

### Save the child scopes on the parent controller

```
// parent controller

controller: function($scope){
                    var childs = [];

                    this.reset = function() {
                        angular.forEach(childs, function  (child) {
                            child.clear();
                        });                            
                    };

                    this.addChild = function (childScope) {
                        childs.push(childScope);
                    };
                },

// child link function

link:function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

                    ctrl.addChild(scope);

                    scope.clear = function () {
                        scope.isSelected = false;
                    };                     

                    scope.select = function(){
                        ctrl.reset();
                        scope.isSelected = true;
                    };
                }
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you. Btw, I believe we need to use `$scope.$broadcast()` rather than `$scope.$emit()` in order to propagate the event downwards (parent -> child).  Other then that it works great!